# RAM memory requirements for Machine Learning model (Latent semantic indexing)

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory-management, nlp, gensim

I would like to calculate/estimate the amount of memory required for a LSI model with Ticket Volume of 40,000, no. of topic 20,000 and dictionary size of 80,000. The data type used is float64 which consumes 8 bytes. I am relying on gensim package's lsi model. [gensim reference](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/lsimodel.html).

Can you someone please suggest the RAM memory calculation formula/method?

Comment: The people who've closed this don't seem to understand the question, which is a well-formed programming question about how to estimate much RAM a particular algorithm (LSI) of a particular library (Gensim) will take on a particular well-specified problem. Working coders hit this sort of issue all the time, & thus it's a good question with both specific answers (for the exact parameters supplied) & more generic techniques (to know how to figure this out in the future on related problems).

Comment: I don't believe any portion of the Gensim library uses an `np.float64` when an `np.float32` would suffice, so I believe your assumption that `float64` is relevant is incorrect. To know precisely the RAM used by scenario would require a close udnerstanding of the source code - https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/lsimodel.py - to see, especially, its max RAM allocation during training. I'm not familiar enough with the inner workings of `LSIModel` to offer a simple calculation, but I can offer a few tips that may get you 'close enough': …

Comment: First, the dominant influence on overall RAM usage in Gensim models is usually the *size of the vocabulary* (more than the number of training items, which can be streamed in), and further influenced by the metaparameter choice of *number of topics/dimensions*. Second, peak RAM usage during training usually isn't appreciably more than final steady-state RAM usage – and you can get a rough idea of final steady-state RAM usage by seeing how much space a model takes up on disk, via any files created by `model.save(path)`. …

Comment: Thus: you may want to try running `LSIModel` on a tiny subset of your data, with same model parameters, taking note of the effective vocabulary of that test – then observe peak RAM usage (via system tools) & final storage-size-on-disk of that test model. Then, try it on 2x as much data, again noting how much larger the vocabulary word-count has become, & the size-on-disk. Etc. This should eventually create an *experimental* estimation formula: X% more in vocabulary size means Y% more on disk - & the resulting informed estimate of what your full model will require may be close enough.